# Why is the class called RunnableFuture<T> instead of CallableFuture<T>?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

The following code is from [AbstractExecutorService](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.java#AbstractExecutorService):

```
 /**
 * Returns a <tt>RunnableFuture</tt> for the given callable task.
 *
 * @param callable the callable task being wrapped
 * @return a <tt>RunnableFuture</tt> which when run will call the
 * underlying callable and which, as a <tt>Future</tt>, will yield
 * the callable's result as its result and provide for
 * cancellation of the underlying task.
 * @since 1.6
 */
 protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
    return new FutureTask<T>(callable);
 }
```

I fail to see why the class of the returned object from `newTaskFor()` would be called RunnableFuture instead of CallableFuture? What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RunnableFuture` represents a specific concept : a future result whose computation can be explicitly performed by a worker thread by calling `run()`.

Since worker threads are usually not interested in the results of the computations they perform, they use `run()` that doesn't return the results. And threads that are interested in these results can obtain them from `get()` as soon as the worker thread finished the computation.

Answer (score 6):

The point of a `RunnableFuture` is:

1. It's a `Future`
2. It's a `Runnable`

It converts the `Callable` you already have into something that is both a `Future` and a `Runnable`. It covers the exact use case it is intended to cover. If you have a `Callable` and need a `Future`, there's the `FutureTask` constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is `Runnable`, i.e. has a `public void run()` method, rather than `Callable`, which would have a `<T> public <T> run()` method.

Comment: the signature of `call()` method is this `V call() throws Exception;` .By the question I meant to say why they didn't put a   `V call() throws Exception;`  method and name it CallableFurture because all they are doing here is they are wrapping a `Callable` in a `FutureTask`

Comment: @Subhra Then I suggest you edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps simple because the API architect was never asked this question?

Since we don't know we can only quess: there is a newTaskFor(Runnable...) method, which returns a RunnableFuture, which is called such because it extends Runnable and Future.

Then there was a newTaskFor(Callable...) method added - since the Callable can also be wrapped into a FutureTask which implements RunnableFuture, they just did it instead of inventing a new interface just to be clear that it was going to wrap a Callable: along the Occam's razor principle using the most simple possible solution, i.e. one that already exists.